# How to generate unique integer from string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a few classes with heterogenous keys - int and string - and i want to work with them through common interface. It's pretty simple just convert int to string but it obviously will cause perfomance issues. Another options I see are box them to "object", which also doesn't seems perfect, or somehow generate unique integers from string (there will be no joins between former "string" and "int" so they must be unique only in "string" domain) and the quetsion here is "how"?

Comment: Why converting int to string obviously will cause performance issues?  I think it is faster than string.GetHashCode().

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just take `string.GetHashCode()` which returns an `int` from a `string` with very low collision probability.

Comment: "very low" isn't enough and i don't want to create collision resolution mechanism, it seems like overhead here

Comment: @user1437713 - What you want is not possible.  Any algorithm like what you want has a risk of collisions evens GUIDs are not actually unique.

Comment: Ramhound, depends on the version.

Comment: it could be millions, and there is 1:10 proportion between "string key" objects and "integer key", that's why i don't want convert int to string

Comment: GUIDs are unique enough here ) it's a good idea actually, except for they are 4 times bigger than int

Comment: @user1437713 - What you want is not possible without collisions at least by just using integers.  So use GUID v4....

Comment: @Ramhound you are probably right. well, at least i've tried. thank you all for participating

Comment: GetHashCode generate negative numbers as well

Comment: I think the biggest problem with this approach was missed in the comments: GetHashCode will generate a _different value_ for each execution of the application. This code will yield _different_ values for each time the process is started: `"".GetHashCode()`. Its easy to test, just write a console app, like `Console.WriteLine("".GetHashCode().ToString());` and run the application twice.

Comment: @Ted: This is true only for .Net Core, which came out way after this post was written. In .Net Framework you always get the same hash code.

Comment: Oh, i didnt know that. Thats even more crazy :-)

Answer (score 4):

Be wary of `string.GetHashCode()`.
The .Net documentation states https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx

> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for
> identical strings states can differ across versions of the.NET
> Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a
> single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even
> differ by application domain

Comment: Almost even worse: `GetHashCode` will generate a _different value_ for each execution of the application. Its easy to test, just write a console app, like Console.WriteLine("".GetHashCode().ToString()); and run the application twice. The output will be different each time.

Answer (score 3):

As @tudor pointed out GetHashCode is the supported way of producing hash code from strings (and other objects). Unfortunately there is no way to do such transformation so an integer represent unique strings unless you put severe restrictions on set of strings.

I.e. if your strings short enough (i.e. 2 Unicode or 4 ASCII characters) than there is obvious one-to-one mapping, or if your set of strings is limited and known in advance.

Some reading on the subject: the underlying problem called [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) which guarantees collision. Due to [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) collisions are very likely to happen on reasonably small sets.